# Vl53l0x ToF Sensor turn on without gnd

Tags: sensor, ground, infrared, distance, floating

My ToF sensor turn on if I not connected its ground pin to common ground (I let it float). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what pins do you have connected, but I assume that two of them are at opposing voltages. Integrated circuits have these protections diodes, through which current can flow if one of the pins is at a higher voltage than VDD or lower voltage than VSS (ground)
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/ESD-protection-circuits-with-novel-MOS-bounded-Ker-Chuang/874045671fe3a0247f5bf1894208ce50209358d3/figure/0

Say you set VDD to 3V, leave GND unconnected and an input (pad) to 0V. Current is going to flow through the lower diode between the pad and ground to power the circuit